# Python Keycloak - There is a way to get user by email?

Tags: python, api, keycloak

I need to retrieve a user by his email. How can I achieve this?

Im using Python 3.10 with the library python-keycloak (https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) but there isn't a method to achieve this.

Someone know how to do this? Really thanks

Comment: [documentation](https://python-keycloak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#documentation) shows `keycloak_admin.get_user_id("example@example.com")` but I don't know if it is what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python keycloak is just a wrapper that passes the parameters to keycloak rest endpoint for users. In the [REST api docs for users resource](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) you can see that the query param `email` can be passed.

Your code should look like this:

```py
users = keycloak_admin.get_users({"email":"foo@bar.com"})
```

Comment: I didn't write the solution I found on my own yesterday, but it is exactly as you wrote what I did! I was going to post my solution soon, but I see you answered it first, so I'll mark my question as solved. Thank you very much for your cooperation :)

Comment: @Paul How about searching for a user with a custom attribute?